# How do I write an address that I do not have a problem with the folder if I move it?

Tags: java, image, icons

```
 ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("resource/17.jpg");
```

this is my problem .To run this image I have to write the full address but I want to write the address of the folder if the folder was transferred to another system. Run this icon again

Comment: Hi, could you explain the problem better and give more context?

Comment: you may add a variable in the path that is mapping to your static folder, and make it changeable in the config file.